# I cannot click on next in Configure Image Asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, assets

When I open the Configure Image Asset in Android Studio by right clicking on res and selecting new -> Image Asset, and after selecting the path to my image and resizing, I cannot press next because the next button is greyed out.

I've tried using the default image as well but the same problem prevails. Much appreciated if someone could shed some light.

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozRVt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your compileSdkVersion version should be above v26 to use adaptive icons.

For below v26 API Level you can use Legacy Icons Only in Icon Type

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid. I have just upgraded SDK to V29. I've run the code several times but I still see the error 'Project must be built with SDK 26 or later to use adaptive icons'.

Answer (score 0):

The very reason for that is written right there in the bottom:

`Project must be built with SDK 26 or later to use adaptive icons.`

You must be using Android SDK 25 or lower to build your project. Bump it up from API Level 26 or later as mentioned by @Ranjeet by **changing your module-level `build.gradle` file**. Should work fine that way.

Personally I use latest Android API level 29. It is strongly recommended that you always compile with the latest SDK. You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs etc.